# Enum in Eclipse Scrapbook

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, eclipse-juno, jpage

Not sure if this is a bug or if I am going a bit crazy.. Am trying to do some quick testing of enums in an Eclipse jpage Scrapbook (using JDK 1.7.0_02, Win XP 64-bit, Eclipse Juno)

```
class A {
    enum Month {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC}
}
A a = new A();
```

When I try execute this I get:

> The member enum Month can only be defined inside a top-level class or interface

And this is what happens if I move the enum out of the class definition.

```
enum Month {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC}
Month.valueOf("JAN");
```

These are the errors I got for the above:

> The member enum Month can only be defined inside a top-level class or interface
>
> Month cannot be resolved

Comment: Assuming class `A` is an inner class, move it to be an outer class and this should fix it.

Comment: This seems to be a bug related to the fact that Eclipse will actually wrap your scrapbook code into a class to be run. Combined with the fact that only a subset of modifiers can be applied to classes defined in the scrapbook. The solution would be too break the enum out of the class definition.

Comment: Hi @Perception - I get pretty much the same error if I move the enum outside the class. I updated the original post to reflect this.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram I tried moving the `enum` are it worked fine. Try doing a `Project->Clean...` on your project...

Comment: @Perception I am still getting the same output (JDK 7) - the code in my second snippet is the only contents of the jpage. Now I am confused.

Comment: @Reimeus - not sure how that relates to my code though - I don't have an inner and outer class defined; the scrapbook literally contains just what I put above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is to move the enum itself out of the jpage into a new class. So I make the class like so:

```
package test;
public class Test {
   public enum Month {
      JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC;
   };
}
```

Then in the jpage:

1. right click and select "Set Imports"
2. click "Add Packages" and enter/select the **test** package.

Then my jpage will have the following code only:

```
Test.Month.valueOf("JAN");
```

Comment: Which unfortunately defeats the purpose of using an Eclipse Scrapbook file in this case. If I have to create a new class for the enum, I might as well forget the jpage, add a main method to Test and put the rest of testing code there..

Comment: Wrote this up here: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/enums-in-eclipse-scrapbook-page.html. Plus, in case this is a bug that can be fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401883

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry if what I'm going to say is a little stupid, but shouldn't you declare the enum as a public member of class A? Enumerations inside a class are inherently static, but not public. In your first example what happens if you try to declare it as public?